# CSS scale+animation blurs the image in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have a large element that has multiple animated (rotating) images, and you can zoom in and out on the entire div (which changes its scale transform). However, if an image element is created while the div is zoomed out, when I zoom back in I can see that the image is very blurry, as if it the image was downscaled when the element was created. A possible workaround would be to hide & show the image every time I zoom, but that doesn't sound like the best solution.

Here's a snippet demonstrating the issue ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjdrmwa9/)). Click on the first link to get a blurred image (sometimes only breaks on the second click), and on the second link to get a good image.

```js
$(".try-1").click(function() {
  $(".image").remove();
  $(".pos").css("transform", "scale(0.4)").append("<div class=\"image\"></div>");
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".pos").css("transform", "scale(1.4)");
  }, 500)
});
$(".try-2").click(function() {
  $(".image").remove();
  $(".pos").css("transform", "scale(1.4)").append("<div class=\"image\"></div>");
});
```

```css
.clicky {
  color: #00f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.clicky:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.div {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
}
.pos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 250px;
}
@keyframes rotating-cw {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  top: -150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/grJ6I3k.png);
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  animation: rotating-cw 30s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="clicky try-1">Create &amp; zoom in</span> | <span class="clicky try-2">Zoom in &amp; create</span>
<div class="div">
  <div class="pos">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
.pos {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 250px;
}
```

Comment: That makes it always slightly blurred (probably to match 100% scale, since the image is 511px and the element is 300px). Also the property is crossed out in devtools, while it definitely has effect.. is that another bug?

Comment: i have to think about it. this was the only workaround that worked for you, right now. but the thing is that the image is not a vector image, so i think when you make it bigger there is some quality change inevitably. if you even  make the image the same big size at first without anything you get the same quality.

Comment: The image itself is 511px, but with the perspective fix, chrome always downscales it to 300px before stretching it to the display size. It would work in my production code because my element is actually of the correct size, though.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using requestAnimationFrame but a simpler and more straightforward solution is to tell the browser to again initialize the image's container

```
$(".try-1").click(function() {
  $(".image").remove();
  $(".pos").css("transform", "scale(0.4)").append("<div class=\"image\"></div>");
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".pos").css("transform", "scale(1.4)");
    // Here, after we scale up the element again append 
    // the .image element but first remove it
    $(".image").remove();
    $(".pos").append("<div class=\"image\"></div>");
  }, 500)
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjdrmwa9/1/)

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, it seems hiding and showing the .pos element again is enough (I can't remove the image because in my actual code it is in before/after pseudo elements).